# Understanding deadlocks in java

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock

Given below is an example I found about deadlocks and it works. My question is how does `currentThread()` work? And also A and B are not created as threads specifically, i.e like:

```
Deadlock d=new Deadlock();
Thread A=new Thread(d)
```

How does the code still work?

```
class A {
    synchronized void foo(B b) {
        String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        System.out.println(name + " entered A.foo");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (Exception e) {System.out.println("A Interrupted");
        }
        System.out.println(name + " trying to call B.last()");
        b.last();
    }

    synchronized void last() {
        System.out.println("Inside A.last");
    }
}

class B {
    synchronized void bar(A a) {
        String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        System.out.println(name + " entered B.bar");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (Exception e) {System.out.println("B Interrupted");
        }
        System.out.println(name + " trying to call A.last()");
        a.last();
    }
    synchronized void last() {
        System.out.println("Inside A.last");
    }
}

public class Deadlock implements Runnable {
    A a = new A();
    B b = new B();

    Deadlock() {
        Thread.currentThread().setName("MainThread");
        Thread t = new Thread(this, "RacingThread");
        t.start();
        a.foo(b); // get lock on a in this thread.
        System.out.println("Back in main thread");
    }

    public void run() {
        b.bar(a); // get lock on b in other thread.
        System.out.println("Back in other thread");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Deadlock();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean, how does currentThread work? It returns the current thread. A thread is created, the first thread still exists.

Comment: `A` and `B` are not `Thread`s they are classes, the `Thread`s try and get monitors on the classes. `currentThread` returns the thread that the method was called from; how does it work? Take a look at the source code.

Comment: Where is the A thread created? I am a newbie to java. @Dave Newton

Comment: `Thread.currentThread()` is how you can access the thread running the line of code.  The `setName(...)` is a noop, btw, because the thread is already running.

Comment: we called the constructor 'Deadlock' from the main method.How does that mean that 'A' is the thread running the line of code @Gray

Comment: A isn't the thread. A is used by the thread. The threads are the Deadlock threads. What do you mean, where is it created? There's the initial thread, and you create another one.

Comment: In the constuctor, the `main` thread is the current thread and you create a new `Thread` (RacingThread). So the application's `main` thread races that.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a fairly confusing example of a deadlock - it adds other noise the the problem.

A very simple example can be achieved by using `Lock` objects like so:

```
public class App {

    private static final Lock LOCKA = new ReentrantLock();
    private static final Lock LOCKB = new ReentrantLock();

    private static final class Locker1 implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    LOCKA.lockInterruptibly();
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                    LOCKB.lockInterruptibly();
                    System.out.println("Locker 1 Got locks");
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    return;
                }
                LOCKB.unlock();
                LOCKA.unlock();
            }
        }
    }

    private static final class Locker2 implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    LOCKB.lockInterruptibly();
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                    LOCKA.lockInterruptibly();
                    System.out.println("Locker 2 Got locks");
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    return;
                } finally {
                    LOCKA.unlock();
                    LOCKB.unlock();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        executorService.submit(new Locker1());
        executorService.submit(new Locker2());

    }
}
```

The application starts two threads in an executor, we then have those threads call two runnables.

These runnables try and acquire locks on the two `Lock` objects in the opposite order.

So `Locker1` locks `LOCKA` then waits a few milliseconds. `Locker2` locks `LOCKB` and waits a few milliseconds, they they try and acquire the other lock.

The situation is that `Locker1` waits for `LOCKB` and `Locker2` waits for `LOCKA` for ever as the other thread never releases it.

You can see this fairly clearly in the thread dump for those threads:

```
"pool-1-thread-1" - Thread t@8
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - waiting to lock <7725204d> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync) owned by "pool-1-thread-2" t@9
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:834)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:894)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1221)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lockInterruptibly(ReentrantLock.java:340)
    at com.boris.testbench.App$Locker1.run(App.java:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - locked <7567e1fa> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync)

    - locked <5ad52411> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

"pool-1-thread-2" - Thread t@9
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - waiting to lock <7567e1fa> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync) owned by "pool-1-thread-1" t@8
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:834)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:894)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1221)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lockInterruptibly(ReentrantLock.java:340)
    at com.boris.testbench.App$Locker2.run(App.java:51)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - locked <7725204d> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync)

    - locked <6856c528> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)
```

We can see that `pool-1-thread-1` wants a lock on the lock owned by `pool-1-thread-2` and `pool-1-thread-2` wants a lock on the lock owned by `pool-1-thread-1`.

This situation will continue forever, hence deadlock.

You code achieves the same result but instead of using two threads spawned manually it uses the application main thread (spawned by the JVM) and one thread spawned manually.

It also uses `synchronized` methods in two `Object`s rather than two `Lock` objects.

Answer (score 2):

`Thread#currentThread()` = Thread that is currently running. Everything runs in a Thread. When you start a java app, you have only one thread that we can call the Main Thread. So, a call to a `main` method is nothing else but the start of a running thread.

I commented where you may be having some doubts.

```
// Deadlock is a Runnable. So, it can be wrapped inside a Thread Object to be started.
public class Deadlock implements Runnable {
    A a = new A();
    B b = new B();

    Deadlock() {
        // currentThread now is the one that instanciated this Deadlock object.
        Thread.currentThread().setName("MainThread");
        // here the Deadlock is wrapped inside a thread object. Notice the `this` qualifier.
        Thread t = new Thread(this, "RacingThread");
        // here the thread wrapping deadlock is started.
        t.start();

        a.foo(b); // get lock on a in this thread.
        System.out.println("Back in main thread");
    }

    public void run() {
        b.bar(a); // get lock on b in other thread.
        System.out.println("Back in other thread");
    }

    // here is the start of the Main Thread! :D 
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // the program is started inside the Deadlock Class constructor.
        new Deadlock();
    }
}
```

Can you understand better now?

Answer (score 1):

Some good answers here (+1 to @Ralf and @bmorris591) but I thought I'd explain your code a bit more.

There are 2 threads here.  The "main" thread which runs `main(...)` and the `"RacingThread"` started from within the `Deadlock` constructor.  Btw, it is very bad form to start a thread in a object constructor.  It would be better to do something like:

```
  Deadlock deadlock = new Deadlock();
  new Thread(deadlock, "RacingThread").start();
```

Also, inside the `Deadlock` constructor it calls `Thread.currentThread().setName("MainThread");`.  This is trying to set the name of the current running thread which is (confusingly) the "main" thread since it did the `new Deadlock()`.  Unfortunately the `setName(...)` call is a noop if the thread is already running so it doesn't do anything.

Next, inside the `Deadlock` constructor, the `"RacingThread"` is constructed with `this` as the `Runnable` and `start()` is called which forks the thread and has it call the `Deadlock.run()` method.  This takes some time so most likely the `a.foo(b);` line is reached *before* the `run()` method is called.

Your `a` and `b` objects are *not* threads as has been pointed out already.  They are just objects that are being used to demonstrate the locking.  The deadlock happens because the main thread is calling `a.foo(b);` and then the `"RacingThread"` calls the `b.bar(a);` inside of the `run();` method.  `a.foo(...)` is `synchronized` on `a` and then tries to call `b.last()` which is `synchronized` on `b`.  `b.bar(...)` is `synchronized` on `b` and then tries to call `a.last()` which is `synchronized` on `a`.  That is a classic deadlock.

Hope this helps a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are assuming that the synchronized keyword is a global lock. It is not. It simply locks(serializes) access the the method to which it is applied. Given that your example does not call the same method on the same class from 2 separate threads, no reason it wouldn't work.

Comment: My 2 cents as well, I see where it shouldn't hinder operations in this case.

Comment: The `synchronized` keyword on the method locks the _object_ not the method.  `b.bar()` and `b.last()` lock the same _object_.

Answer (score 0):

A deadlock occurs when 2 threads take two resources in different orders :

- T1 take r1
- T2 take r2
- T1 try to take r2 <=== blocked, waiting for resource r2
- T2 try to take r1 <=== blocked, waiting for resource r1
- system dead

This program:

```
public class DeadLock implements Runnable {

   String name;
   Object r1;
   Object r2;

   DeadLock( String name, Object r1, Object r2 ) {
      this.name = name;
      this.r1   = r1;
      this.r2   = r2;
   }

   @Override public void run() {
      if( name.equals( "T1" )) {
         System.out.println( name + " try to take r1" );
         synchronized( r1 ) {
            System.out.println( name + " has taken r1" );
            try{ Thread.sleep( 1000L ); }catch( InterruptedException x ){}
            System.out.println( name + " try to take r2" );
            synchronized( r2 ) {
               System.out.println( name + " has taken r2" );
            }
         }
      }
      else {
         System.out.println( name + " try to take r2" );
         synchronized( r2 ) {
            System.out.println( name + " has taken r2" );
            try{ Thread.sleep( 1000L ); }catch( InterruptedException x ){}
            System.out.println( name + " try to take r1" );
            synchronized( r1 ) {
               System.out.println( name + " has taken r1" );
            }
         }
      }
   }

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      Object r1 = new Object();
      Object r2 = new Object();
      new Thread( new DeadLock( "T1", r1, r2 )).start();
      new Thread( new DeadLock( "T2", r1, r2 )).start();
   }
}
```

Outputs:

```
T1 try to take r1
T2 try to take r2
T1 has taken r1
T2 has taken r2
T2 try to take r1
T1 try to take r2
```